# How to create a C console application in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I haven't found any extension, or tutorial to make and execute a C console application in the VSCode Terminal.

A simple program like

```
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World!");

    return 0;
}
```

And have the output in the VSCode Terminal.

Does someone know how to realize this? And/or are there solutions?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: Did you try it? What problem did you face?

Comment: @Bodo I don't know how to try it, because I haven't found a documentation about how to do it. That's why I posted the question. Therefore, no, I haven't tried it.

Comment: Actually I think this would be a fine question to have an answer for at Stack Overflow, wince it is quite narrow in scope, when you think about it...

Comment: But build environment is important. Linux? Mac? Windows? If Windows, which C compiler/toolchain?

Comment: @hyde It would be on Windows and gcc

Comment: Try this: Make sure you have C/C++ extension installed. There may be serveral, so try to find the best one... Probably one from Microsoft should be tried first. Then open the .c file, open command palette (ctrl-shift-P), type "run" and see if there is an option to run it, do so.

Comment: Note that you will usually want to use a makefile, or cmake maybe. But that's a broader topic, and not really relevant until you have a project which consists of several files.

Comment: If the above works, then you could just write an answer yourself (write it as if you were answering question of someone else), simply explaining how the file in question can be run under VS Code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There actually is an extension for c/c++ on VSCode:
[image: Image of the extension]
When you click the arrow in the top right (to run the file) you will be asked which compiler you want to use. In our case we can use the gcc compiler:
[image: Screenshot of possible compilers for c]

Then you can paste your code into a `.c` file and run it with the compiler. It should automatically also execute the binary and print your output into the debug-console:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World!");

    return 0;
}
```

```bash
Hello World!
```

You even have a debugger, if you set certain breakpoints!
[image: Code halting on line 4, because a break point was set]

Extra:
Make sure that you have the correct OS set in the bottom right (in the status bar), so your c code compiles for your machine specifically.

Comment: for those who do not get the run button displayed: You can open the command search with "CTRL + shift + P" and type in "run" and select "Run C/C++ File".